# add postfix info to url django

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I realize stackoverflow does a trick with the url for making it more human readable

It has the following pattern

> stackoverflow.com/questions/id_question/title_question

for example we have

> stackoverflow.com/questions/36676286/counter-with-lambda-over-map-java8

And if you delete part of the title question and you go to the url left

> Example : stackoverflow.com/questions/36676286/counter-with-la

You are still redirect to the correct url.

Looks it only reads until the id, and then it adds the title info to the url , how I could add this information to the url?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by capturing both id and slug in the URL but only using the id to look up the post; then you can compare the post's slug with the one you got, and redirect if they are not equal. Something like (using Django 2.0 path syntax):

```
path('questions/<int:id>/<slug:slug>', views.question, 'question')
```

...

```
def question(request, id, slug=None):
    post = Post.objects.get(id=id)
    if slug != post.slug:
        return redirect('question', id=id, slug=post.slug)
    ...
```